# SSL Pinning not working for React Native . error: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found

Tags: react-native, ssl, pinning

I am using MaxToyberman /react-native-ssl-pinning library to enable the SSL pinning through react native for android . I am trying with public key pinning. even try with native module option but no luck.  Getting below error error: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.

we try to generate public key from .cer certificate from below command  echo | openssl s_client -servername  -connect :443 2>NUL | openssl x509 -pubkey -noout | openssl pkey -pubin -outform DER | openssl dgst -sha256 -binary | openssl enc -base64

fetch(
'https://API_URL',
{
method: 'GET',
pkPinning: true,
sslPinning: {
certs: [
'sha256/AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA=',

```
      ],
    },
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
      e_platform: 'mobile',
    },
  },
)
  .then(response => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(response.bodyString, null, '\t'));
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log('err ' + err);
    console.log(`error: ${err}`);
  });
```

};

Expected Output : Response.ok true

Current Output :  error: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.